# User quivalent "Vote to close" functionality for mods

Tags: feature-request

As a mod I would like to sometimes just add a vote-to-close rather than singlehandedly close a question. Is there any way to implement a simple drop down option for (normal user|mod) functionality.

Specific cases are when it could be appropriate to get a mod consensus - currently we try and decide in chat or the Teacher's Lounge, but that isn't always possible.

The alternative is for mods to await downvotes from users, and then act accordingly.

Comment: This has been requested before on MSO.  I'll try to find the link.

Comment: Found two topics on this.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66245/the-binding-moderator-vote-problem-on-beta-se-sites discusses how moderator closures are an especially sensitive issue on Beta sites where the site definition may still be a bit ambiguous.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-vote is the question you're asking here, and the `feature-request` has been set to `status-declined`.  There seems to be a *lot* of community support behind it, but the powers that be are firmly rejecting it.

Comment: @iszi - cheers. I had a quick look but hadn't spotted those.

Comment: As lszi stated, this is a repeated question. I vote to close it =p (jk)